# Gradle plugin dependency exists but isn't found during the build

Tags: java, gradle

It seems like what I have is correct, but Gradle is still not finding the plugin.

My plugins clause looks like:

```
plugins {
    id "io.codearte.nexus-staging" version "0.8.0"
}
```

The build error looks like:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/local/MAGICLEAP/doprea/development/java/JenkinsPipelineUnit-1.1/build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'io.codearte.nexus-staging', version: '0.8.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.codearte.nexus-staging:io.codearte.nexus-staging.gradle.plugin:0.8.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

However, the CR appears to have it:

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.codearte.nexus-staging/0.8.0

..and the dependency clause provided there is identical to what I already have.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try the latest version 0.11.0 too? Did you try the old mechanism of including the plugin? Did you double check that the new mechanism of adding plugins apply to your project setup? Please see the "About the new plugin mechanism" section on the plugin page https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.codearte.nexus-staging#new-plugin-mechanism-info

Comment: Actually, the old syntax worked. Any idea why the new one didn't? It seemed like the usage was simple-enough that there wouldn't have been any complications.

Comment: This depends on your project setup. I put together an answer and noted possible reasons.

Comment: I think the problem you're having is with the `plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace` part. However, I can't seem to find any further information on when/how the restriction to the `org.gradle` namespace is applied. I know that a plugin published to the Gradle portal that _doesn't_ use this namespace needs to be approved before it is publicly available, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here...

Answer (score 1):

The plugin page states two ways of including the plugin (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.codearte.nexus-staging#new-plugin-mechanism-info). The one `for plugins DSL for Gradle 2.1` and the one `for use in older Gradle versions or where dynamic configuration is required`. The Gradle plugins DSL version has some constraints and did not work in any case, e.g.

1. Can only be used in build scripts.
2. Cannot be used in conjunction with subprojects {}, allprojects {} etc.
3. The plugins {} block must also be a top level statement in the buildscript

If the plugins DSL version did not work for you should use the other way of including it.

Comment: Yes. I was previously able to resolve using that legacy style.

Answer (score -1):

Adding

> rootProject.buildFileName = 'build.gradle.kts'

in settings.gradle file on the 1st line should help you.

@Reference: [reference link](https://github.com/antoniolg/Bandhook-Kotlin/issues/38)

Comment: I believe .kts is for kotlin projects

Answer (score -1):

Add this code android/settings.gradle

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
    include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
    project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine')
}
```